# Do I need a PCR test for travelling from UK to Poland

Tags: uk, air-travel, covid-19, uk-citizens, poland

I'm going to be travelling to Poland soon for a week but I can't work out if I need to get a PCR test for traveling?

- I'm fully vaccinated (with proof)
- Travelling via air (RyanAir)
- Filling in a passenger locator form

---

[gov.uks poland entry requirements page](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/poland/entry-requirements#entry-rules-in-response-to-coronavirus-covid-19) only mentions:

> If you are travelling to Poland from an internal EU/Schengen country by air you must hold a negative COVID test result issued in the 48 hours prior to arrival into Poland, unless you meet one of the exemptions listed above.

which makes no sense given that the uk isn't an EU country anymore but it does also say

> You do not need to self-isolate if you are: ...
> fully vaccinated

[RyanAir](https://www.ryanair.com/ie/en/useful-info/map-page) just says

> Necessary Covid-19 documentation can include ... Proof of negative PCR/antigen test

Comment: For completeness, what is your citizenship? Checking Timatic using UK as your nationality indicates double vaccination with an approved vaccine allows entry with no pre-travel PCR requirement but YMMV depending on your exact circumstances https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external.php?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b The UK gov page you link to states the same as far as I can see

Comment: Ah sorry, British national! and thanks for the link!

Comment: Does your itinerary have a transit point? If so, where?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over and the question is no longer relevant.

Answer (score 0):

> **Persons vaccinated against COVID-19 are exempt from quarantine**. This
> applies to persons who have a certificate of vaccination with a
> vaccine which has been granted a marketing authorisation within the
> European Union. Full vaccination is recognised 14 days after
> completion of the vaccination process.

Source: https://www.gov.pl/web/coronavirus/outside-the-european-union-schengen-area-turkey

Comment: That doesn't seem to answer the question "do i need a PCR test?"